# Mediaplayer error (-38,0) and error (1,-1010)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

So i am trying to get a mediaplayer to work, but on first install the music doesnt start playing (i think it's because of permissions needed for the visualizer). But everytime afterwards it plays just fine.

code:

```
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bik);
    mPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

Log cat:

```
11-23 17:18:29.979 28329-28329/com.waro.blockevader E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
11-23 17:18:29.979 28329-28329/com.waro.blockevader E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
11-23 17:18:29.979 28329-28329/com.waro.blockevader E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1010)
11-23 17:18:29.979 28329-28329/com.waro.blockevader E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
11-23 17:18:29.979 28329-28329/com.waro.blockevader V/MediaPlayer[Native]: isPlaying: 0
11-23 17:18:29.979 28329-28329/com.waro.blockevader E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
```

The file format is .mp4

Thanks for the help.

Edit:

What i meant by everytime after;

Everytime after i gave permissions and RESTARTED the app, the music starts playing just fine and no errors are given.

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

Comment: What does "But everytime afterwards it plays just fine." mean?

Comment: Sorry man, still too vague. 
What permissions are you granting your application?
Are you starting the video in onCreate() of your Activity?

Comment: I am starting the music in my onResume(), but onCreate() gives the same error. I am granting RECORD_AUDIO and MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by changing a part in the onResumse(),

As expected it was indeed the permission causing havoc,
i had:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (!mPlayer.isPlaying() && !mpCreated) {
            initTunnelPlayerWorkaround();
            init();
        } else {
            mPlayer.start();
            mVisualizerView.link(mPlayer);
        }
    } else {
        cleanUp();
        mPlayer.start();
        Log.i("boop","biep");
    }
```

And finally discovered by that log it was going into the else, meaning it was calling the cleanUp(); method

And in the cleanUp() method i had:

```
private void cleanUp() {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mVisualizerView.release();
        if(!mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.pause();
        }
    }
}
```

The 2nd if was causing havoc (duh) and i fixed it by changing it to:

```
private void cleanUp() {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mVisualizerView.release();
        if(mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.pause();
        }
}
```

I know this is a weird and specific answer, but maybe someone else who had the same struggle can find out why he or she was having problems.

Have a great day all and thanks for trying to help

~Waro (dh19, couldnt use waro sadly)

Comment: Glad you figured it out! As you can see from your original post, it would've been difficult for us to help you debug it. The code in this ANSWER is nowhere to be found in your original post. I know sometimes you just need to think out loud but next time try posting all the code thats involved :)

Comment: To be honest, i had no idea this was the part causing it, but ill try to be more specific next time :)

Answer (score 5):

You are getting two different errors. The first one

```
E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
```

means that you try to call the `MediaPlayer` without preparing it first.

The second error

```
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1010)
```

means that the media is unsupported. You can see the error codes [here](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/include/media/stagefright/MediaErrors.h#37) and [here](https://github.com/android/platform_external_opencore/blob/master/pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h)

Comment: but i called onPrepared()? And if i am not calling it then why does it work after i gave permissions and restarted my app. Same goes for error number 2. Neither is shown when i restart my app after permissions were granted

Comment: @dh19 That's what the errors stand for. I can't tell you anything else with the provided info.

Comment: Yea i understand but that doesn't really solve my issue :/

Comment: Wow, the links to check error code names are mind blowing. I could never decipher the error codes and thought they were useless. This is great help!

Comment: I am getting "E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1010)" error after ~20 minutes of radio stream playback (HLS). Any idea why? (If it was an unsupported format, mediaPlayer would throw that error instantly, not after 20m)